# C failed while allocating memory

Tags: c, arraylist, malloc

I am creating an arraylist in C, each time I try to reallocate the array (for expanding it) the third time, I get this error message:

> malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
>   Aborted

My code is the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "arraylist.h"

ARRAYLIST* newArrayList() {
    ARRAYLIST* arraylist = malloc(sizeof(ARRAYLIST));
    arraylist->size = 0;
    arraylist->increasingStep = 2500;
    arraylist->capacity = arraylist->increasingStep;
    arraylist->array = calloc(sizeof(char), arraylist->increasingStep);
}

void arraylist_put(ARRAYLIST* list, char* value) {
    if (list->size >= list->capacity) {
        arraylist_expand(list);
    }

    list->array[list->size] = value;
    list->size++;
}

void arraylist_expand(ARRAYLIST* list) {
    list->capacity += list->increasingStep;
    char** tmp = list->array;
    list->array = calloc(sizeof(char), list->capacity);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < list->size; i++) {
        list->array[i] = tmp[i];
    }
}

void arraylist_free(ARRAYLIST* list) {
    free(list);
}
```

And the main file:

```
int main(char** argv, int argc) {
    ARRAYLIST* tmp = newArrayList();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
        arraylist_put(tmp, "TEST");
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    printf("Capacity: %d\n", tmp->capacity);
    printf("Size: %d\n", tmp->size);

    arraylist_free(tmp);
}
```

Does anybody know the solution? Or had a similar scenario?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `realloc`?  And `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: newArrayList() should actually `return arraylist;`. Is this an oversight when you pasted the code here, or is that indeed how your real code looks like?

Comment: You don't return the allocated pointer from newArrayList

Comment: yeah, does this even compile?  `newArrayList()` is declared to return ARRAYLIST* but it doesn't.  I bet there's some kind of heap magic happening here, where you get lucky with the first two allocations.

Comment: Also note that the code is leaking memory in arraylist_expand(). The old memory is never freed before allocating the new one. To avoid this, you should be using realloc() instead, as already pointed out by Carl.

Comment: Also note that `arraylist_free` should `free(list->array);` - that's another memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
calloc(sizeof(char), N)
```

allocates a block of memory N bytes big (because `sizeof(char)` is 1) which you then treat as an array of N pointers.  That's going to overflow and corrupt your heap.

You need to do this:

```
calloc(N, sizeof(char*))
```

Note that it's `char*`, not `char`.

(I've also reversed the arguments to match what `calloc` expects, but actually that shouldn't make any difference.)

Comment: Looks like you agree with me - unfortunately without knowing the type of `arraylist->array`, it's hard to say.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I'm assuming that `char** tmp = list->array;` tells us everything we need to know.  :-)

Comment: Good catch - didn't see that one.

Comment: Note: the form `arraylist->array = calloc(sizeof *arraylist->array, arraylist->increasingStep);` will avoid this kind of coding error.

Answer (score 2):

Your program has some weird logic, but your real problem is that you've allocated space to store 2500 `char` objects, but you're storing 2500 `char *` objects before reallocating.  That  means you've overwritten the end of your array.  It looks like that at one point you overwrite some important `malloc` bookkeeping structure.  Without the definition of `ARRAYLIST` it's hard to say how much you're overwriting or when it might happen, though.